# Execute in memory binary with c

Tags: c, linux, x86-64, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm currently stuck on my c project, I'm trying to run a program in memory with C language, but all the time i have segmentation fault.

First I have a simple `hello_worl.c`, I compile it and I have the output `hello_world`.

2nd I transform the `hello_world` to C header like that :

`xxd  -i hello_world > hello.h`

(Content of the hello.h)

```
unsigned char hello[] = {
...
}
unsigned int hello_len = 16696;
```

Finally, I create the program `main.c`, which seem like that :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include "hello.h"

int main ()
{
    int (*my_hello) () = NULL;

    // allocate executable buffer
    my_hello = mmap (0, sizeof(hello), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC,
                MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

    // copy code to buffer
    memcpy (my_hello, hello, sizeof(hello));
    __builtin___clear_cache (my_hello, my_hello + sizeof(my_hello));  // GNU C

    // run code
 my_hello ();


}
```

I base this code with this 2 topics :

- [How to get c code to execute hex machine code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960721/how-to-get-c-code-to-execute-hex-machine-code)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176111/how-to-dump-a-binary-file-as-a-c-c-string-literal

In this case I am trying to do with hello_world but as you can gess, I would like to do it with other programs (like linux utilities).

I am not very good at C, so any help is welcome !

Comment: How did you compile `hello_world`? Are you sure it doesn't contain extra headers?

Comment: If not, this may be helpful. [linux - Is there a way to get gcc to output raw binary? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647359/is-there-a-way-to-get-gcc-to-output-raw-binary)

Comment: Use `execve` to load the binary and execute it.

Comment: Or if you want to load code and run it within your program, make a shared library instead of an executable, and load it with `dlopen()`.

Comment: Thanks @MikeCAT for your response, for compilation I am using gcc with gcc hello_world.c -o hello_world.

Comment: Thank @stark, but execve doesn't fit to my need because, When i will compile my main.c, I don't want to use hello_world, I want only 1 program for both.

Answer (score 6):

This is a much more complicated problem than you think it is :/

The only "simple" option would be to `write()` that embedded array to a file in `/tmp` and `execve` it, to take advantage of the kernel's ELF program loader and the system's dynamic linker.  This would effectively be creating a self-extracting executable wrapper.  (Typically you'd want to compress the file with `zstd` or gzip / deflate, at least that's the normal reason for having a self-extracting wrapper.)

---

**A Linux executable starts with metadata; you can't just load the whole thing into memory and jump to the first byte.** (This is true for everything except DOS `.com`).

The **ELF program-headers** say which parts of the executable file need to be mapped to what relative position in memory (normally by the kernel's ELF program-loader which sets up the mmap-like mappings).

e.g. .data might be next to .text on disk, but the headers will have them mapped some distance apart so array out-of-bounds is likely to fault instead of read code.  Also, the `.bss` section needs to be allocated separately, either past the end of .data or as a separate MAP_ANONYMOUS mapping so it's initially filled with zeros.

Your wrapper program already has a stack, but the _start entry point of the executable will be **expecting argc, argv[], and envp[] to be on the stack as specified in the System V ABI doc**.  (e.g. x86-64 System V).

Also, x86-64 and i386 System V ABIs used on Linux expect the stack pointer to be 16-byte aligned on entry to `_start`.  *Not* like a function call where it should be aligned before the `call`, resulting in `RSP % 16 == 8` at a function entry point.  You can expect some x86-64 library functions to crash if the program relies on the incoming stack alignment.

---

It's also probably dynamically linked, so you'd need to process the relocation metadata to hook up its GOT (and PLT) entries to symbols from libc.so.6 and any other libraries it uses.  i.e. you'd need to implement an ELF program-loader, and the dynamic linking functionality of `ld.so`.

**You could avoid that part if you statically link libraries**, e.g. compile `hello_world` with **`gcc -static-pie -fPIE`** to link a static but **P**osition-**I**ndependent **E**xecutable, so it could hopefully work at any load address randomly chosen by mmap.

PIE code may still contain absolute addresses as static initializers, like `static char *ptr = foo;`. The CRT `_start` code is responsible for applying those relocation fixups in a static-pie ([How are relocations supposed to work in static PIE binaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62586808/how-are-relocations-supposed-to-work-in-static-pie-binaries)). Jumping to the ELF entry point will run that code.  It should work by reading metadata mapped into memory as per the ELF headers, so if you got that right it might well Just Work.  But if not, you might have to code carefully to avoid addresses as static initializers.

IDK if the static `libc.a` you'd be linking would have been compiled with `-fPIE` though, so might itself contain absolute addresses (maybe even as immediates in machine code as *32-bit* absolute addresses, which would make linking into a PIE impossible on x86-64: [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux)).

---

I guess **another option would be to make your embedded executable a non-PIE (`gcc -fno-pie -no-pie -static`), and use `mmap(MAP_FIXED)`** to map it into the right place in virtual address space.  (Or use the "hint" address for mmap without MAP_FIXED, and return an error if it doesn't put it where you asked: that means something else is already using that space in your virtual memory space.  Of course if you're going to jump to its `_start`, it's effectively taking over your process and will not return.  It will eventually `_exit`, or execve something else.  But you'd still have a problem if you blew away the code that copies and jumps.)

So to avoid address-space conflicts, make your wrapper program a PIE (the default for GCC on modern Linux distros), so it will get mapped to `0x555...` instead of `0x400000`, or use a custom linker script for one or the other so they can both be non-PIE but using different base addresses.

More about PIE (Position-Independent Executable):

- [What is the -fPIE option for position-independent executables in gcc and ld?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463150/what-is-the-fpie-option-for-position-independent-executables-in-gcc-and-ld)
- [What are the differences comparing PIE, PIC code and executable on 64-bit x86 platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28119365/what-are-the-differences-comparing-pie-pic-code-and-executable-on-64-bit-x86-pl)
- [What's the difference between "statically linked" and "not a dynamic executable" from Linux ldd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61553723/whats-the-difference-between-statically-linked-and-not-a-dynamic-executable) PIE with no libs vs. static-pie

---

**None of this will avoid having to parse the ELF headers somehow to find the entry point to jump to, instead of the head of the buffer.**  (As well as to map the segments properly)

You could do that alongside `xxd`, though, with a script to parse `readelf` output and emit a C var into your .h like `const size_t entry_offset = 1234;`.

Note that the `Entry point address:  0x5b20` in readelf output is a *memory* address, not a file-offset, although for a PIE they might be the same thing.  Check the program headers to see what mapping contains that virtaddr, and compare the (file) "Offset".  With standard GNU/Linux toolchain defaults, usually the virtual memory address is `0x1000` higher than the file offset.

(If you're looking at a non-running PIE executable or library; when run those addresses will be relative to a base randomly chosen by the kernel, typically starting with `0x5555...`.  i.e. look at typical code addresses in GDB before / after using the GDB `start` command, like `disas main`)

Comment: Thank you very much @Peter Cordes, for all this solutions path, and this detailled explanation ! I will try, and make reseaches about that !

Answer (score 2):

You're jumping to `my_hello` correctly, but that's just the ELF header for `hello_world`, which is not executable code. At the very least you need to find the entry point of the code, and you probably need to perform some relocations, which will require being very familiar with the ELF file format (`libelf` will help, though) - if you don't know what that means then I'm afraid a quick answer on StackOverflow won't help you!

Essentially, what you're trying to do is write a program that acts as a dynamic linker*, which is a lot (like a *lot*) of work. If this is for anything other than blind curiosity, you probably want the `exec()` family of functions. If you're determined to continue down this path then (i) good luck to you and (ii) you *need* to learn how to debug assembly.

* This is very different to the toolchain's linker (i.e. you're trying to write `ld-linux`, not `ld`/`collect2` - have a good read of the `ld-linux` `man` page).

Edit: Start of `.text` -> entry point, as pointed out in comments.

Comment: ELF executables have an "entry point" address as metadata separate from the section headers.  The entry point does *not* have to be at the start of the `.text` section, although it often is in compiler-generated code.  (In fact, section headers are optional and are omitted entirely by FASM when it assembles directly into an executable instead of a .o; an ELF program-loader should only look at the program headers.)

Comment: Also, even in a dynamically linked executable (where ld.so is the "ELF interpreter"), I think the kernel's ELF program-loader still takes care of mapping the main executable's segments into memory, as well as ld.so's code and data.  If you `strace` a tiny executable with a `_start` that exits, you don't see open/mmap to make that happen.  So the OP would need to implement that segment-mapping functionality (including setting up a BSS that's not part of the image on disk) separately from resolving dynamic symbol relocations (GOT / PLT) if they really want it to work for a dynamic executable.

Comment: @John Graham thanks for our answer, i will explore this solution !